# Connect to Microsoft Exchange 2013 (64bit) via SQL Server (or VB)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vbscript, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to get all emails from a folder from a email account in Microsoft Exchange 2013. It would be great to do this in TSQL (otherwise in VB or VBS), but I couldn't find a lot on the web.

Do anybody know a good solution? I need just the mails from the folder, nothing else :-)

I've found these "Web services in Exchange", but I'm not sure, if this solves my problem or if it's the best way.

Another idea is to use IMAP or POP3? Is this possible? Unfortunately I'm not an expert for exchange server :)

Comment: Accessing Exchange server (mails) is complicated, that's why the Exchange Web Services exist together with e.g. the Exchange managed API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx. I doubt that accessing it directy from SQL Server is a viable option, you will have to go through code (as most people do from C variants). I'm not familiar with the possibility of using VB(S) in SQL server, but it certainly is doable from VB(S). People (not me) have done this and even Microsofts documentation gives VB(S) examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using Exchange Web Services via the Managed API is the easiest way to access what you need from Exchange.  This can be done with a few lines of code from C# or VB.NET.  There are many samples on MSDN for doing this.  Using IMAP, POP3, or any other interface will likely be much clunkier and way more LOC.  If you must do this in the SQL Server environment, I believe there is a way to run .NET/CLR code from within SQL, I just have not done so in my travels.